# How to control the back buttons and continue with a dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need help in jQuery.
    I would use a dialog box in my form. I would like when I click on the "Backward" button to display the dialog box. By clicking "Yes" I can go back to the previous page of my pages, and if I click the No button I stay on the current page. By clicking on the "Forward" button I continue on the next page without alerting the dialog box. Please, how do you do that?
    Below my basic source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery-ui-1.10.4/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>

        <title>Test</title>
<script>
let validation = function(form) {

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Yes: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        document.getElementById("myForm-previous").submit();
      },
      No: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

  return false;

}
</script>
    </head>

    <body>


    <div id="dialog" title="Confirmation">
<p>Warning!!!
You will lose your data!
Do you want to continue ?</p>
    </div>
<form id="myForm" name="myFrom"/>
        <input type="file"/><br/>
        <input type="file"/><br/>
        <input id="myForm-previous" value="BackWard" type="submit" onclick="return validation()"/><br/>
        <input id="myForm-next" value="Forward" type="submit"/>

</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for this solution

```
const backButtonListener = () => { 
    const answer = confirm('are you sure?'); // here you can toggle your popup
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
}

window.onpopstate = backButtonListener;
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/dLha9xxk/)